# Pandas equivalent of MS Excel's concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with mixed datatypes. I'm trying to find a way to create a column of concatenated values that I will later use as an indexed field.

My dataframe:

```
col1    col2    col3
str     num1    float1
str1    num3    float2
```

My desired output:

```
col1    col2    col3    combined_id
str     num1    float1  strnum1float1
str1    num3    float2  str1num3float2
```

What I've tried:

```
df['combined_id'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply("".join, axis=1)
```

this gives an error of:

```
expected str instance, float found
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: `df['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)`

Comment: @NoobVB ah, that worked. For my own education. why `agg` instead of `apply`?

Comment: `apply` will also work if used after `.astype(str)`, - just showed it can be done in a different manner. Not sure which way is faster for a larger data, - test it :)

Comment: `.agg` can work with multiple functions in a list, e.g. `.agg(['min','max'], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NoobVB mentioned in comments, I used `astype(str)` to solve it:

Here is my updated line:

```
df['combined_id'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].astype(str).apply("".join, axis=1)
```